# An inequality by induction: Engel, Problem 24, page 208

Tags: inequality, induction

I am reading Arthur Engel's *Problem Solving Strategies*, Section 8, The Induction Principle, Problem 24 [image] with its solution [image] I do not understand the second inequality in the solution on page 216. This is valid when the sum of the fractions $1/a_i$ is small enough. How do we show that?

Is there an alternative proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$0<1-\frac{1}{a_1}-\cdots-\frac{1}{a_m}=\frac{a_1\cdots a_m-\widehat{a_1}a_2\cdots a_m-a_1\widehat{a_2}\cdots a_m-\cdots-a_1\cdots\widehat{a_m}}{a_1\cdots a_m}$$

where $\widehat{a_i}$ means that the term of the $i$th index is left out. Since that fraction on the right is positive and the numerator is an integer, the numerator is at least $1$. Therefore

$$1-\frac{1}{a_1}-\cdots-\frac{1}{a_m}\ge \frac{1}{a_1\cdots a_m}$$

which is exactly the second inequality.

The next two steps should be clear (the assumption that $\sum_{i=1}^m 1/a_i=1$ and the induction hypothesis, respectively).

Let us prove the last inequality from that chain in the book:
For $i=m+1,\dots,n$, we define $k$ by setting $i=m+1+k$. Then $0\le k\le n-m-1<n$.

Now estimate
 $i!=(m+1+k)!\ge m!(m+1+k)\ge m!m+m!(1+k)$. Therefore

$$\sum_{i=m+1}^n \frac{1}{2^{i!}}< \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2^{m!m}}\frac{1}{2^{m!(1+k)}}\le\left(\frac{1}{2^{m!}}\right)^m\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{m!(1+k)}}}_{\le \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^j}=1}\le \left(\frac{1}{2^{m!}}\right)^m$$

Taking $m$th roots we get the claimed inequality.

Now altogether we have shown that $a_k\ge 2^{k!}$ for all $k=1,2,\dots,n$. This leads to a contradiction to the assumption $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i}=1$ because

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i}\le \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2^{i!}}<\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^j}=1$$

Comment: Very cool proof for the second inequality. Thank you. I got the rest of the proof before, but thank you for being thorough.